# How to change background-color in wp-admin/post.php

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

I want to change background-color or add text "It's draft" or anything in wp-admin/post.php according to the value of the post status.
I know how to change it on the list page(wp-admin/edit.php).
But I don't know what to do in wp-admin/post.php

Is there a dedicated filter / hook or html-class?

Comment: which color you want to change?

Answer (score 0):

In your functions.php:

Use the admin_body_class hook to add the post status to the body of the post backend.
Then create a custom stylesheet and enqueue it with the admin_enqueue_scripts hook.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I could do I wanted to!
Thank you very mach!!

Comment: My pleasure. Glad it helped.